# Is there an analytic $f(z)$ s.t. $f(\frac{1}{n+1})=\frac{1}{\ln^2(n+1)}$ for each $n$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Is there an analytic $f(z)$ in the open unit circle s.t. for each normal $n$, we get:

$$f(\frac{1}{n+1})=\frac{1}{\ln^2(n+1)}$$

My solution:

they way I thought about this is to define:

$$g(z)=f(z)-\frac{1}{\ln^2{\frac{1}{z}}}$$

we can find a series  $\big\{Z_n\big\} = \frac{1}{n+1}$ that converges to zero, whcih is included in $D$ "the open unit circle" which is the domain in which $f$ is analytic.

so by the identity theorem we get that $g(z) \equiv 0 $.

$$\Longrightarrow  f(z)=\frac{1}{\ln^2{\frac{1}{z}}}$$

but $f(z)$ isn't analytic because we have a singular point at $z=0$, and another thing, I'm thinking about the $\ln(z)$, as long as we are not defining a branch cut, there is no way we can say its analytic in the unit circle, right?

I would be glad to get some clarifications and some views about what I did.

Comment: $\sin(z)$ has a sequence of zeros that accumulate at $\infty$ but it is still not constant equal to $0$. To apply the identity theorem you would need to prove some condition on $g$ at $z=0$.

Comment: @Bettybel but the zeroes of $sin(z)$ do not converge to $z=0$. the condition on $g(z)$ must be thats its analytic, but we know its not analytic at $z=0$ , which means I can't use it from the first place.
and here I'm confused.

Comment: It makes no much difference $0$ or $\infty$. Think of $\sin(1/z)$

Comment: @Bettybel well , $sin(\frac{1}{z})$ is not analytic at $z=0$. so thats why we can't say its identically $0$ by the identity theorem. exactly like the case of $g(z)$ , we need a convergence point that its inside the analtytcation region.
in case of $sin(z)$ , {$Z_n$}=$\pi n$ doesn't converge into the analytic region.

Comment: Correct. To apply the identity theorem you need the function to be analytic at the point. You would need, somehow to argue why $g$ is analytic at $z=0$.

Comment: Let me give you a hint that goes in slightly different direction. Observe that $1/\ln^2(n+1)\to0$. That means that if such an $f$ exists, then $f(0)=0$. Therefore $h(z)=f(z)/z$ is analytic on the disc and $h(1/(n+1))=(n+1)f(1/(n+1))=(n+1)/\ln^2(n+1)$. What should be $h(0)$?

Comment: @Bettybel I thought about this. very interesting. I think $h(0)$ must be equal to $f'(0)$. but $h(0)$ this way turns out to be $\infty$. so we reach that $f'(0)=\infty$. but the last one can't be because $f$ is analytic and have final coeffecients in its taylor expansion. contradiction. am I right ?

Comment: Yes, that's how that proof would go.

Answer (score 0):

You do not just have a singular point at $z=0$. The function
$$
f(z)=\frac{1}{\log^2 (1/z)}=\frac{1}{\log^2 z}
$$ 
can not be defined in $\mathbb D\setminus\{0\}$.

It can only be defined in $\Omega\subset \mathbb D\setminus\{0\}$, where $\Omega$ is a simply connected region.

For example
$$
\Omega=\mathbb D\setminus (-1,0].
$$